# Hiding blank Columns in worksheet without changing the pivot table in the same workbook

Tags: excel, pivot, formula

I came across a situation where I have a data set in Range A2 to F10 and a Pivot table in Range  A12 to G26.

I need to hide column C and E as there is no data in column C2-C7 and E2-E7[image], but hiding these column will disrupt the pivot table way.

I am unable to come up with a smart way to do that after lot of research, wanted to check with the mates here , if they have any idea or suggestion .

Comment: Move one or the other to a separate sheet - IMHO, stacking data on top of a pivot is not the best design, for this very reason (and more.)

Comment: Does moving/re-do the pivot table @ H1 cell solve your concern?